# How to combine elements from a List without duplicates using Java

Tags: java, list

I am trying to iterate and combine values from a list. My list is [A,B,C,D]. and I am looking for a way to output the following.

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

Here is my code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
      for (int i = 0; i<list.size()-1; i++){
         for (int k = 0; k<list.size()-1; k++){
             if (list.get(i)!=list.get(k+1)){
                System.out.println(list.get(i)+list.get(k+1));
               }
            }
         }
```

Code output

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CB //Note this value: I already have BC -- and I consider BC==CB
CD
```

I am not sure if scanner is an option here... 
it gets more messy if I have more elements in the list. more items in the list means more duplicates such as xx, yy, xy yx.

Comment: There are a gazillion articles on the web for how to generate combinations. Please do some **research**.

Comment: I truly don't understand if the question is valid and there are million answers out there,  you can mark it as duplicate with reference to the answer. it's easier to be part of a team......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
    for (int x = 0; x < list.size() - 1; x++){
        for (int y = x + 1; y < list.size; y++){
           System.out.println(list.get(x) + list.get(y);
        }
    }
```

Inner loop should start at outer loop's index + 1 and go on till the end of the list. This will work assuming you do not have duplicates in `list`

Also to compare strings, you would need to use `.equals()`. `==` will always evaluate to `false` if they are two different `String` instances i.e. :

```
String a = "apple" //Same value but twi different String instances
String b = "apple"
System.out.println(a==b) // Prints false
System.out.println(a.equals(b)) Prints true
```

`==` operator compares the **object references** not the *value*, where as `.equals()` compares the **values** in the two objects. So `==` will check if the two objects refer to the same `String` instance or not.

Comment: Thanks anon!! I greatly appreciate including the detail explanation!!

Comment: Sure no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the second for loop to iterate from `i+1`. That should give all the permutations. Here's the changed for loop:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
      {          
          for (int k = i+1; k < list.size(); k++)
          {
                System.out.println(list.get(i)+list.get(k));
          }
      }
```